# How to skip sending of build context without using .dockerignore?

Tags: docker

Without using a `.dockerignore` file, is there a way to skip sending of build context when building an image via the following command?

```
docker build .
```

In other words, I would like the build context to be empty, without a need to manually create an empty directory that I would then pass to `docker build`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can run

```
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

From the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--):

> This will read a Dockerfile from STDIN without context. Due to the lack of a context, no contents of any local directory will be sent to the Docker daemon.

Comment: Can I pass file in any way to the context?

Comment: @404pio I believe the syntax `< Dockerfile` reads a file called Dockerfile (no extension). If you need to read another file, just replace `Dockerfile` with the path to it.

Comment: @AndreLuus thanks, I know. I was curious if I can add files to context, not to Docker file. After a lot of searching it is not possible. Cheers

Comment: Understood. Do you mean you wish to supply context files without writing them to disk first? Sounds like you should post a dedicated question for that and link it from here.